# How to produce all binary vectors of length n with k zero elements sequentially?

Tags: matlab

How to produce all binary vectors of length n with k zero elements sequentially?

I know how to produce all combination of such sequences once. But I am looking for an algorithm to build them one by one.

This codes generate all of binary vectors of length `a+b` with `a` zero elements and stores them in `V`:

```
function V = build_2(a,b)
C = nchoosek(1:a+b,b);
V = zeros(size(C,1),a+b);
for i=1:size(V,1)
    V(i,C(i,:)) = 1;
end
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. I edited the question to show what I've tried

Comment: I assume you need to generate them one by one because all at the same time take too much memory, right? Otherwise you could generate them all and then index rows

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, exactly that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
for n = 0:2^(a+b)-1
    aux = dec2bin(n,a+b)-'0'; %// or use: aux = de2bi(n,a+b);
    if sum(aux)~=b
        continue
    end
    v = aux; %// desired result
    disp(v) %// do stuff with this v
end
```

This generates all binary vectors of length `a+b` and skips those that don't have exactly `b` ones. [`bin2dec`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html) is used for generating each binary vector. Since `bin2dec` gives a string, subtracting `'0'` converts to a numeric vector.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it time-consuming to do `dec2bin(n,a+b)-'0';` and to check `if sum(aux)~=b`? since time is really important in my code.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Yes, it would be better to directly generate each desired vector, instead of generating every possible vector and then skipping unwanted ones. As for `dec2bin`: if you have the appropriate toolbox, use `aux = de2bi(n,a+b);` instead; maybe it will be faster

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Yes, sorry. Corrected!